# Shell Bash Replace or remove part of a number or string

Tags: bash, shell

Good day.

Everyday i receive a list of numbers like the example below:

```
11986542586
34988745236
2274563215
4532146587
11987455478
3652147859
```

As you can see some of them have a 9(11 digits total) in as the third digit and some dont(10 digits total, that`s because the ones with an extra 9 are the new Brazilian mobile number format and the ones without it are in the old format.

The thing is that i have to use the numbers in both formats as a parameter for another script and i usually have do this by hand.

I am trying to create a script that reads the length of a mobile number and check it`s and add or remove the "9" of a number or string if the digits condition is met and save it in a separate file condition is met.

So far i am only able to check its length but i don`t know how to add or remove the "9" in the third digit.

```
#!/bin/bash



Numbers_file="/FILES/dir/dir2/Numbers_File.txt"

while read Numbers
do

    LEN=${#Numbers}

    if [ $LEN -eq "11" ]; then
        echo "lenght = "$LEN
    elif [ $LEN -eq "10" ];then
        echo "lenght = "$LEN
    else
        echo "error"
    fi
done < $Numbers_file
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the third character of any string with `sed` as follows:

```
sed 's/.//3'
```

Example:

```
echo "11986542586" | sed 's/.//3'
1186542586
```

To add a 9 in the third character:

```
echo "2274563215" | sed 's/./&9/3'
22794563215
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are *absolutely* sure about the occurrence happening *only* at the third position, you can use an `awk` statement as below,

```
awk 'substr($0,3,1)=="9"{$0=substr($0,1,2)substr($0,4,length($0))}1' file
1186542586
3488745236
2274563215
4532146587
1187455478
3652147859
```

Using the `POSIX` compliant `substr()` function, process only the lines having `9` at the 3rd position and move around the record not considering that digit alone.

> substr(s, m[, n  ])
>   Return the at most n-character substring of s that begins at position m, numbering from 1. If n is omitted, or if n specifies more characters than are left in the string, the length of the substring shall be limited by the length of the string s

Comment: Yeah, it only happens on the third digit, it is the Brazilian mobile format, else it is not recognized as a number which is why ill be working on some other ifs.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of text manipulation tools that will do this, but the lightest weight is probably `cut` because this is all it does.

`cut` only supports a single range but does have an invert function so `cut -c4` would give you just the 4th character, but add in `--complement` and you get everything but character 4.

```
echo 1234567890 | cut -c4 --complement
12356789
```